# Making websites hosted on localhost available to all on network

Tags: iis, network-share, localhost

I have a website hosted in IIS on my local PC

If I go to http://localhost or http://192.168.1.1 my site comes up.

But what must I do to let other users on our network to see my site?

I am using Windows 7.......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either allow them to connect to your machine using the `http://192.168.1.1` address or you can create a name that maps to 192.168.1.1. How you create the name depends on what infrastructure you have. If you have a local DNS server then add the name pointing to 192.168.1.1 into that. Failing that you could add the name to the [hosts file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172218) on you machines.

Comment: I did try by just giving them just my IP but it does not work....what must I do in IIS?

Comment: Open port 80 on firewall?

Comment: check that you have port 80 on your firewall open

Answer (score 0):

Check that Windows Firewall allows external connections from local IP addresses on your network to port 80.  Opening ports on [this page](http://blog.aquabirdconsulting.com/?p=257) explains how to do that.